# Is there away to fix this The Isolation Tree code? I am getting NameError: name 'classify_data' is not defined

Tags: python

Here is the code;

```
def isolation_tree(data,counter=0, max_depth=50,random_subspace=False):

    # End Loop if max depth or isolated
    if (counter == max_depth) or data.shape[0]<=1:
        classification = classify_data(data)
        return classification

    else:
        # Counter
        counter +=1

        # Select feature
        split_column = select_feature(data)

        # Select value
        split_value = select_value(data,split_column)
        # Split data
        data_below, data_above = split_data(data,split_column,split_value)

        # instantiate sub-tree      
        question = "{} <= {}".format(split_column, split_value)
        sub_tree = {question: []}

        # Recursive part
        below_answer = isolation_tree(data_below, counter,max_depth=max_depth)
        above_answer = isolation_tree(data_above, counter,max_depth=max_depth)

        if below_answer == above_answer:
            sub_tree = below_answer
        else:
            sub_tree[question].append(below_answer)
            sub_tree[question].append(above_answer)

        return sub_tree
```

I am getting the `NameError: name 'classify_data' is not defined`.

Comment: maybe define the function -- or import it...?

Comment: Thanks, however, I have tried to import but seem like there isn't any package as such. How do I define the classify_data please? I am still in learning process of python.

Comment: I don't know what it is supposed to do, so I'm afraid you'll have to do that yourself. How to define functions is covered in the tutorial (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it. 

def classify_data(data):
    
    label_column = data.values[:, -1]
    unique_classes, counts_unique_classes = np.unique(label_column, return_counts=True)

    index = counts_unique_classes.argmax()
    classification = unique_classes[index]
    
    return classification

Comment: If you think it will be helpful to future visitors, you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

def classify_data(data):

```
label_column = data.values[:, -1]
unique_classes, counts_unique_classes = np.unique(label_column, return_counts=True)

index = counts_unique_classes.argmax()
classification = unique_classes[index]

return classification
```